# Oracle:Concurrent program with 5 parameters

Tags: oracle11g

I would like to know if there's a builtin concurrent program in Oracle that takes 5 parameters as shown below:
Mail Server 
Email From 
Email Subject 
Email To 
Email Cc

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to do with this program?

Comment: @FlyingFoX . I just want to do some test. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is it is not clear what that program should do with those parameters. Maybe explain what kind of tests you want to do.

Comment: You want to create table and insert these parameters??

Comment: @Ghayel, yes indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create table email(
email_id number(14) primary key,
sendingDate timestamp(0) default sysdate,
Subject varchar2(110),
EmailFrom varchar2(110),
EmailTo varchar2(110),
EmailCc varchar2(110),
Email varchar2(3900)
);

create sequence email_seq
start with 1 increment by 1;

create or replace trigger email_trig
before insert on email
referencing new as new
for each row
begin
select email_seq.nextval into :new.email_id from dual;
end;
/

insert into email(subject,emailFrom,emailTo,emailCc,email) 
values('Subject','from@gmail.com','to@gmail.com','cc@gmail.com','message body');
```

Comment: I will try this out...I just thought if there's already builtin program. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer and added pk + timestamp + sequence to generate auto pk + trigger